# Ordering a Django queryset based on the sorting of a sorted set from redis

Tags: python, django, sorting, redis

I have a sorted set from redis. The sorted set contains both ids of objects and their sorting scores.

Next, I have a Django queryset, consisting of objects whose sorted ids were contained in the aforementioned redis sorted set.

I need to sort this Django queryset according to the placement of ids in the *redis sorted set*. What's the fastest way to accomplish this?

---

I'm trying the following:

```
    dictionary = dict(sorted_set) #turning the sorted set into a dictionary
    for pk, score in dictionary:
        obj = queryset.get(id=pk) #get object with id equalling pk 
        score = object  #assign the object to the 'score' value of this key-value 
    result = dictionary.values() #making a list of all values, that are now in sorted order
```

The for loop above fails for me with a `too many values to unpack` error - I'm still debugging it. Nevertheless, I also feel there are probably faster ways to do what I'm trying to do, hence I asked this question. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your for loop with:

```
result = sorted(queryset, key=lambda item: dictionary[item.pk], reverse=True)
```

This will exception out if anything in the qs is not in the redis result - use `dictionary.get(item.pk, ...)` with some sane default instead of `dictionary[item.pk]` if that can happen.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I'll get back to you on this

Comment: What if certain ids *don't exist* in the queryset, but exist in the sorted_set? In that case, the lambda function would return a `key` that doesn't exist in `queryset`. The result automatically excludes those entries?

Comment: `sorted` sorts the elements of the first argument - `queryset`, in this case. `key` just defines how to calculate the sort priority for each element of the first argument, so it would ignore elements that are in the sorted set but not in the queryset. Another example that might more cleanly show the behavior would be sorting a list of strings by length - `sorted(list_of_strings, key=len)`. Any string can have its length computed, but only ones in the initial list will be in the sorted result.